# Reset database causes heroku custom domain to issue 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I added a [custom domain](http://ly.cent.tech) to my heroku app sometime last week and its been pointing well up until this last night.

A huge error made me reset my database using the `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` command.

Since then, attempts to visit my app from the custom domain issues a `404, page not found` error.

However, when I visit the app directly through its [heroku](http://lycent.herokuapp.com) domain name, it works without issues.

I've tried restarting the server, re-adding the domain name even after confirming its there (using `heroku domains`).

I'd be glad if anyone could help with this error. Thanks.

Comment: I guess your custom domain is working now..It might take some time to reflect.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Start with checking the error from the Heroku logs.

Comment: RORDeveloper No its still not working. I added it last week and its been working since then. It stopped working since I reset the database.
@SimoneCarletti the logs confirm the get request to home actually got there, but returned a 404. Sorry for my late response. I went to do something else. its saturday morning here in Nigeria.

Comment: @Cent well, show these lines from the logs.

Comment: @EugZol Apologies again for my very late response. I had to attend an event I couldn't take my laptop to. I just checked it now and it seems the problem has been rectified. Apparently, Heroku need some time (close to 9 hours). Thanks once again for your effort.